# equation of the tangent line to the graph of $f(x)=\int_{x\sqrt{2}}^{x^2}\ln(t^2+4)\,dt$ at $x=2$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The problem ask for the equation of the tangent line to the graph of 
$$F(x)= \int_{x\sqrt{2}}^{x^2}\ln(t^2+4)dt$$ at the point $x=2$.

I know that I have to do something like $$y-f(a)=f'(a)(x-a)$$ where $a=2$, but really the numbers are really awful or im doing something really wrong, but anyway what will be the correct procedure to resolve that kind of problems?

Comment: I tried to fix your typesetting, but I don't know what you meant by $L$. can you clarify what the integrand is supposed to be? is it just supposed to be $t^2+4$?

Comment: thanks,looks amazing, I didn't know that have that functions.
By L i mean Log in e base(Ln),I copied directly from the notebook and didn't realized that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct procedure is to calculate $f(a)$ and $f'(a)$. So in this case, you need $f(2)$ and $f'(2)$.

To compute $f(2)$, we need to compute $$\int_{2\sqrt{2}}^4\ln(t^2+4)\,dt$$
This integral requires integration by parts; set $u=\ln(t^2+4)$ and $dv=dt$. If you need more help, I will elaborate. (We get $$\int\ln(t^2+4)\,dt=t\ln(t^2+4)-2\int\frac{t^2}{t^2+4}\,dt$$
but $\frac{t^2}{t^2+4}=1-\frac{4}{t^2+4}=1-\frac{1}{(t/2)^2+1}$.)

To compute $f'(2)$, you just rewrite $f(x)$ as $$f(x)=\int_0^{x^2}\ln(t^2+4)\,dt-\int_0^{x\sqrt{2}}\ln(t^2+4)\,dt$$
and then use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus together with the chain rule to conclude that $$f'(x)=2x\ln(x^4+4)-\sqrt{2}\ln(2x^2+4)$$
To get $f'(2)$, just plug in $x=2$.

Comment: Thanks really helped me, the explication what just as expected.